# Spring getResourceBundle cast exception

Tags: java, spring

I am using `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and I want to get all keys of property file.

```
public class ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource extends
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    public Set getKeys(String baseName) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = getResourceBundle(baseName);
        return bundle.keySet();
    }
}
```

On call of `getResourceBundle` an exception is thrown:

```
java.util.PropertyResourceBundle cannot be cast to java.util.ListResourceBundle
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.PropertyResourceBundle cannot be cast to java.util.ListResourceBundle
at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:170)
at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:167)
at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:154)
at com.test.configuration.ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource.getKeys(ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource.java:21)
at com.test.configuration.UserDetailsServiceImpl.reloadAccountsFromProperties(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:92)
at com.test.configuration.UserDetailsServiceImpl.init(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

Message source definition:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="....ras.configuration.ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="10" />
</bean>
```

The resource is loaded properly and I can access its attributes one by one. But I need to get all keys from the file.

GetKeys is called:

```
(messageSource).getKeys("test");
```

UPDATE: I used method getMergedProperties instead of getResourceBundle which still throw exception. Actual solution:

```
public class ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource extends
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    public Properties getProperties() {
        this.clearCache();
        PropertiesHolder propertiesHolder = getMergedProperties(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return propertiesHolder.getProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us your spring  version? ..and  a little more stacktrace could be helpful.

Comment: Sure, sorry for little info. 
<spring.integration.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>

Comment: sorry, but the `getResourceBundle(String baseName)` is none of spring's (at least none of spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE) ...maybe just a wrong import statement: `import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;` ??

Comment: I have the same import. I used getMergedProperties instead of getResourceBundle and its finally working correctly. Anyway thanks for help